# MYSQL Lookup Full Word against Part Word

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to do the following in myself for example with postcodes. I have the postcode **AA1 2AA** in my table there is a record **AA1***. Is it possible to match this up? Reverse of the query below

```
SELECT * FROM destination WHERE postcode LIKE '%AA12AA%'
```

Records in table

```
ID Postcode
1  AA1*
2  AB1*
3  AB2*
4  AC1*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM destination
WHERE 'AA12AA' like replace(postcode, '*', '%');
```

That is, reverse the `like` and use the correct wildcard for SQL.